# Python: validation using cerberus

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, cerberus

I would like to validate a `dict`, where a field may contain either an `int` or a `List[int]`. Also, all `int` must be positive.

I need some help with setting up the schema. The schema below are not working properly. They are not checking for negative numbers. That is, negative numbers are passing the validation, which is incorrect.

```
import cerberus

v = cerberus.Validator()

schema1 = {
    "int_or_list_of_int": {
        "type": ["integer", "list"],
        "schema": {"type": "integer", "min": 0},
    },
}

schema2 = {
    "int_or_list_of_int": {
        "type": ["integer", "list"],
        "valuesrules": {"type": "integer", "min": 0},
    },
}

num1 = {"int_or_list_of_int": 5}
num2 = {"int_or_list_of_int": [5, 10]}
num3 = {"int_or_list_of_int": -5}
num4 = {"int_or_list_of_int": [5, -10]}

# schema 1
assert v.validate(num1, schema1)
assert v.validate(num2, schema1)
assert not v.validate(num3, schema1)  # Evaluates to True
assert not v.validate(num3, schema1)  # Evaluates to True

# schema 2
assert v.validate(num1, schema2)
assert v.validate(num2, schema2)to True
assert not v.validate(num3, schema2)  # Evaluates to True
assert not v.validate(num4, schema2)  # Evaluates to True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `schema` for `int_or_list_of_int` should be inside `int_or_list_of_int` dict. Secondly, `min` should be applied for both integer (inside `int_or_list_of_int`) and list (inside `schema`).

```
schema = {
    "int_or_list_of_int": {
        "type": ["integer", "list"],
        "min": 0,
        "schema": {"type": "integer", "min": 0}
    }
}
```